# How can I query to LDAP the e-mail from Windows User from Java/JNDI?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I have searched around the web but could not find any solution.
Also, I have tried a lot of different solutions, but none works.
Please, keep an open mind while looking to this situation.

Requirements:

- Should use Java/J2SE (Console, GUI, any).
- Do not use any external or third party jar/package only JNDI.
- Do not ask or store user password.
- **Get the e-mail from Windows logged in user in LDAP.**

Assumptions:

- Do not need to dive into the details of LDAP server, it is working on other languages like VBS/.Net/etc. but not Java.

Note:

- The piece of VBS is working even asking for other users (not the one logged in).

  I do not know about LDAP server configuration but the information above should make sense for those who knows it.

Piece of VBS code that is working fine:

```
Dim objSysInfo, objUser<br>
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)
MsgBox objUser.mail
```

**How can I make it work?**

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not the JNDI part, it is getting the user's login name in the same format as provided by `ADSystemInfo.UserName`. You could see whether `System.getProperty("user.name")` returns the right thing, otherwise you are into some ActiveX Bridge thing to emulate the VB code you posted.

The LDAP part just maps very straightforwardly into JNDI, you shouldn't have any problem with that part.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it does not fit the requirements.
When you try in VBS no authentication is required. The user name is used to actually search current user details.
Java/JNDI requires to bind to LDAP server with user/password (SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION as simple) to get current user details. When I try to use as anonymous it throws an exception telling an user name and password is required to search current user details (in VBS it does not require, i.e., user and password bind/login to get current user details).
May you help me to solve this following the requirements?

Comment: VB must be using an implicit or system login somehow. You will have to find out how.

Answer (score 1):

Windows and the VBS APIs use a "SASL GSSAPI mechanism to achieve Single Sign-on (SSO)" form the client to a Active Directory Server.

There are many versions of Windows Active Directory and countless different methods that various parameters could be set in your implementation. So your success may vary.

I found an article that might help point you in the right direction:
http://dmdaa.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/utilize-sasl-gssapi-mechanism-to-achieve-single-sign-on-sso-for-jndi-ldap-client/